# how to add localization in ionic popup

Tags: angularjs, html, css, ionic-framework

i had completed ionic project. i would like to change lanaguages in this code. project title, place holder , button it had changed but popup was doesn't changed. i used this code in controller and language change file.

farmer-ctrl.js :

```
function showPopup () {
  $scope.data = {};
  var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="data.category">',
    title: '{{"farmers_message" | translate}}', //'Enter CoconutType',
    scope: $scope,
    buttons: [
     { text: 'Cancel' },
      {
        text: '<b>{{"save_message" | translate}}</b>',
        type: 'button-positive',
        onTap: function (e) {
          if (!$scope.data.category) {
            //don't allow the user to close unless he enters producttype
            e.preventDefault();

          } else {
            $log.log('yes clicked: ', $scope.data.category);
            addProductType();
            return $scope.data.category;
          }
        }
      },
    ]
  });
  myPopup.then(function (res) {
    $log.log('Tapped!', res);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i had founded by adding translate.instant

```
function showPopup () {
  $scope.data = {};
  var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="data.category">',
    // title: 'Enter CoconutType',
    title: $translate.instant('{{"farmers_message" | translate}}'),
    scope: $scope,
    buttons: [
     { text: 'Cancel' },
      {
        text: $translate.instant('{{"save_message" | translate}}'),
        type: 'button-positive',
        onTap: function (e) {
          if (!$scope.data.category) {
            //don't allow the user to close unless he enters producttype
            e.preventDefault();

          } else {
            $log.log('yes clicked: ', $scope.data.category);
            addProductType();
            return $scope.data.category;
          }
        }
      },
    ]
  });
  myPopup.then(function (res) {
    $log.log('Tapped!', res);
  });
}
```

Comment: So i add my answer 1 hour ago and then you say that you find solution using $translate.instant. The same as my answer. OK,whatever

Answer (score 1):

To add localization in popup you need something like this:

```
 var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
              title: $translate.instant('networkerror'),
                template: '<div><p  translate="onlinemessagepois"></p></div>'
      });
```

where `networkerror` and `onlinemessagepois` exist in your local js files. (Example: "networkerror":"sometext","onlinemessagepois":"someothertext"  )

Note: you have to inject `$translate` in your controller.